# Spawning always start regardless of the status of the variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

so  I created singleton to store some variables

```
public static GameManager instance;

public float score;
public float amoutOfBullets;
public int timeLeft;
public bool timeOver = true;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
}
```

And also script for spawning Cubes which player have to shoot.

```
public List<GameObject> spawnedCubes = new List<GameObject>();

public GameObject Cube;
bool spawned = false;

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(GameManager.instance.timeOver + " at the start of spawning");
    if (GameManager.instance.timeOver == false)
    {
        if (spawned == false)
        {
            spawned = true;
            StartCoroutine(Delay());
        }
        else
        {
            DestroyAllCubes();
        }
    }   
}

IEnumerator Delay()
{
    Vector3 randomSpawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 11), (Random.Range(0.5f, 13)), (Random.Range(20, 100)));
    GameObject newCube = Instantiate(Cube, randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity); 
    spawnedCubes.Add(newCube); 

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    spawned = false;
}

//go through the list with spawnded cubes and destroy them after time is over
void DestroyAllCubes()
{
    foreach (GameObject cube in spawnedCubes)
    {
        Destroy(cube); 
    }
    spawnedCubes.Clear(); 
}
```

The issue which I do not understand is that even tho in my singleton there is

```
public bool timeOver = true;
```

The second script execute the spawning even tho there is a condition in the update method.

```
if (GameManager.instance.timeOver == false)
    {
        if (spawned == false)
        {
            spawned = true;
            StartCoroutine(Delay());
        }
```

Spawning always start regardless of the status of the variable "timeOver"

Comment: how does that ever get changed to false? and what output are you seeing from that debug statement

Comment: Is the GameManager.instance you access in the build script the same instance used elsewhere in the project?